# Is it possible to make a link with 'target' attribute run script on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

****Update: Ultimately I've decided that accomplishing exactly what I want here isn't possible due to the issues it poses to security. Kalle's answer below gives a solution that is closest to what I want to accomplish. 
In order to solve my problem I've created scripts on both pages and will use a sort of push notification that is routed through the server in order for them to communicate.
Thanks for the help!! ****

I have two pages. Both windows already exist independently. Page two has a function declared in JS.

I would like to be able to call the function in window two by clicking a link in window one.

Page 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a title!</title>
</head>
<body style="background: lightblue">

<a href="#" target="my_target" onClick="clicked()">Click Me!</a>

</body>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Window-target" CONTENT="my_target" />
<title>This is a title!</title>
<script type=text/javascript>
    function clicked() {
    alert('test');
    }

</script>
</head>
<body style="background: lightblue">



</body>
```

Comment: Can you post your code here on SO please. If that page changes it outdates the question making it less useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, brand new answer. I hope this is what you were thinking. This is however, when you open page 2 from page 1.. So basically, page 1 would know who page 2 is..

Online example: http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/6832271.php

**Page 1**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ajaxlink {color: blue; cursor: pointer; border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="open_page_2" class="ajaxlink">Open new window</span>

    <br>
    <br>

    <a href="#" target="my_target">Click Me!</a>

    <script>
    $('#open_page_2').click(function(){
        child = window.open('test2.php','page_2','width=600,height=600');
    });


    $('a[target=my_target]').click(function () {
        child.SecondPageFunction();
        return false;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Your seeing page 2!</h1>

    <script>
        function SecondPageFunction () {
            alert('Second page action got triggered!');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for sharing that. Unfortunately though page one won't always open page two. Ups for the demo and the effort. :)

Comment: As far as I know, you only communicate with parents and children. So one has to open another. If page 1 and page 2 are simply opened manually. Then you cannot pass actions between them.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is on the same domain you can get this to work but would have to change the way you were doing it a little.

First off you would have to open it in a popup using this syntax rather than a new tab:

```
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
```

and then you could simply call `newwindow.clicked()` after the popup is called.

### update

just did a quick test and this will open it in a new tab. (sorry its been a while since I used the `open` function.

```
newwindow=window.open(url,'name');
```

Just noticed also that you should wait for the popup to load. So in my Example it would look a little something like this (with jQuery):

```
var newwindow = window.open('http://www.tylerbiscoe.com/vb/new.html');

$(newwindow).load(function(){
    newwindow.clicked();
});
```

Comment: Very good idea, but let's assume the window was already open.

Comment: you could check `if( typeof newwindow == "undefined)`. if that is false than you could just call the function normally. I also updated my answer again for the use with tabs.

Comment: Is there a way to create a reference to a window that already exists?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, because each page can only know whats going on with itself. Since you use `window.open` and assign it to a variable, in a sense it is a child page. I'd be interested in hearing any solutions on how to get that access though

Answer (score 0):

The script must be a part of the page you're opening in the new window. You're absolutely correct about it being a security flaw if it was elsewise allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some query string argument that could be picked up onload by javascript in the page you are opening and call your function if the query string arg is present.

Comment: I thought of that too, but let's assume the page is already open, and I don't want to refresh it.